# How can I display chat widget on mobile without affecting other artifacts?

Tags: icons, ux-designer, position, chat, widget

I want to know a best way to display user chat icons on mobile, as these widgets are overlapping with other artifacts of screen. In mobile due to lack of space, overlapping of icons is appearing. 
What should I do to prevent this issue? Where and how should I place these chat icons for mobile display?
Will it be nice to display these icons in a minimized way in right side of screen? Using this, these icons might appear when user click on that minimized sign.
Please suggest best way to display these.
Sorry for bad English.

[image: This is mobile view of screen]

Comment: Self entitled apps that think they're more important than all the rest, getting in the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I have to mention is that there are so many **circles** on this page that users may be difficult to distinguish them. Better redesign the functions layout.

For your question, I don't think it's suitable to overlapping chat icons on others. You can see now users cannot click "paper pattern" icon and it seems your screen is non-scrollable.

1. Like Robby mentioned, is chatting very important or will be frequently used? If yes, then I agree that chat icons should be placed somewhere obvious and easy to be clicked.
2. If it's possible to redesign the layout, I suggest the chat icon be placed near the "Bell" on the top-right corner. Because it looks like a messages center, which is quite similar to chatting in function type.
3. Maybe you can offer one the most popular one chat icon and fold others. Like use WhatsApp icon and fold Messenger or even Twitter and so on. By clicking a little down-arrow or triangle button, other icons roll out. In this case, you can save space because normally every user has one relatively stable chatting software. And that it's more expandable if you want to add other chatting software icons someday :)